# Using xpath to extract an element out of nested xml document - SOAPUI

Tags: xml, xpath, nested, soapui

Hi below is the xml that I have:

```
<s:Fault>
 <faultcode  xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundat      ion/dispatcher">
a:InternalServiceFault
 </faultcode>
 <faultstring     xml:lang="en-NZ">**<![CDATA[<ns0:Root                       xmlns:ns0="http://NZPost.EAI.UnifiedTracking.Schemas.FaultMessage">
  <FaultCode>NZPUT004</FaultCode>
  <Reason>"**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"    </Reason>
  </ns0:Root>]]**>
 </faultstring>
 .
 .
 .
</s:fault>
```

I want to use assertion in SoapUI to confirm that the response contains the text "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". But I don't know the xpath that should be used in the declare segment to reach the Reason tag.

I am able to navigate to  and  in the above example but the moment I write faultString//FaultCode or faultString//Message it throws an error saying that there is no match in current response.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not navigate the xml content of the Cdata markup using the path but you can get it as a string.. so you can parse it by 
substring-after and substring-before methods or by regular expression

```
substring-before(substring-after(.//*[local-name()='faultstring'] , 'Reason&gt;') , '&lt;/Reason')
```

The result will be

```
"**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"
```

or

```
contains(.//*[local-name()='faultstring'] , '**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**')
```

which will result

```
true
```

I hope this could help

Comment: "You can not access the xml content of the Cdata markup" is false! You can extract the string, and convert that to a XML document. Citation: http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html